# Simple replace with user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, replace

I'm trying to make a 'find and replace' function that takes both values (replaced and replacement) from `Form` element and then replaces all occurances of 'replaced' inside DIV. After that I want it to display an alert with a replaced words count.
Tried to get there with the `for` loop, but something went wrong. Going with plain JS, I'm way too novice to get into jQuery.

```
function wordReplace()
{
    var replaced = document.getElementById('replaced').value.toLowerCase;
    var replacement = document.getElementById('replacement').value;
    var workArea = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
    for (var r=0; r<workArea.lenght; r++)
    {
        if (workArea[r].value.toLowerCase == 'replaced')
        {
            workArea[r].value.replace('\breplaced', 'replacement')
            alert(workArea[r].value.replace('replaced', 'replacement').length)
        }
    }
}
```

And that's my form code, just in case: (ignore `<input type="submit" onclick="replacerHide();"/>` - it's for different function and it works for now)

```
<form> 
   <label for="replaced" class="labelInline">Słowo szukane</label>
   <input type="text" name="replaced" id="replaced"/>
   <label for="replacement" class="labelInline">Zamiennik</label>
   <input type="text" name="replacement" id="replacement"/>             
   <input type="submit" onclick="replacerHide();"/>         
</form>
```

I've read here (in a similliar question of mine) that I should get familliar with `regex` and I did. But have no faintest idea how to apply it to solve my problem. I'm pretty sure I'm onto something with `for` loop here, but other than that I'm empty :/

All and any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

**EDIT - CORRECTED FULLY WORKING CODE**

```
function wordReplace()
    {
        var div = document.getElementById('main');
        var find = document.getElementById('replaced').value;
        var replace = document.getElementById('replacement').value;

        var re_Find = new RegExp(find, 'gi');
        var matches = div.innerHTML.match(new RegExp(find, 'gi'));

        if (matches) 
            {
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(re_Find, replace);
            }

            matches = matches ? matches.length : 0;
            alert(matches);
     }
```

and for the `Form`

```
<div id="form">
        <form id="formularz"> 
            <label for="replaced" class="labelInline">Słowo szukane</label>
            <input type="text" name="replaced" id="replaced"/>
            <label for="replacement" class="labelInline">Zamiennik</label>
            <input type="text" name="replacement" id="replacement"/>                
            <button onclick="replacerHide(); wordReplace();">Podmień!</button>  
        </form>
```

Now it's working as it is supposed to :)

Comment: What does the console output says ? I see *workArea.lenght* , as I know it should have been 'length' so your code should produce an error

Comment: Note that just calling `.replace()` (as in your inner loop) doesn't change the string you called it on. You need to use the string *returned* from `.replace()`.

Comment: Corrected the typo, but even with it still in code console gave me no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are your friend with things like this, as well as [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

By specifying the options `gi` to the `RegExp` constructor you can eliminate the need to check for character case (`i` means case-insensitive).  The `g` means "global" and tells the regular expression you want to repeat the replacement for every instance of `find` that was found (by default, it will replace the first and then stop).

```
// Grab all of the necessary data
var div = document.getElementById('main');
var find = document.getElementById('replaced').value;
var replace = document.getElementById('replacement').value;

// Create our regular expression
var re_Find = new RegExp(find, 'gi');

// Get everything from the div's innerHTML that matches our regular expression
// (this will result in an array of strings, all of which are exactly
// the same as "find")
var matches = div.innerHTML.match(re_Find);

// If there were any matches, use the same regular expression to
// perform the actual replace and update the div
if (matches) {
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(re_Find, replace);
}

// Grab the count of matches that were found and alert the user
matches = matches ? matches.length : 0;
alert(matches);
```

Comment: Did as You suggested and sadly - no avail. Even no errors. I'm starting to think that problem might be somewhere else, but where? :/

Comment: Try putting `console.log(find, replace, div.innerHTML)` after the first 3 `var` declarations, and have a look in the console to see what values they contain.

Comment: Console returns nothing. And I mean it's completely empty. Other functions are working fine.

Comment: I made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/mololarala/1/edit?html,js,output) for you to play with..

Comment: More i fool around with this code the less i know. Used your snippet, got rid of 'submit' in favour of 'button' with my onclick added (i checked in the JSBin - it worked there) and it still doesn't work for me. The thing is I wrote  all functions in one <script></script> set. When I tried to substitute it with jQuery call (as per your JSBin example) console gave me an error with other function (the one that was working all this time). So, I decided to close other functions off in separate <script></> and put this function in new set of markers with jQuery call. Nothing. Am I *that* dumb? :/

Comment: Ok start at the beginning - put a `<button>` on the page, and in a `<script>` tag put `$(document).on('ready', function () { $('button').on('click', function () { console.log('Hi!'); }); });` then fire up the page, click the button and see if you get something in the console.  Then work your way up :)

Comment: I fixed it without jQuery. Thing is I retyped your hint mindlessly and made a typo in `var find = document.getElementById('replaced').value;` (replace instead of correct replaced). But it's all working now. I'll update the question with correct code in a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Try some regexp.

```js
function replace(find, replace, haystack) { 
    return haystack.replace(new RegExp(find,"gmi"),replace);
    }
function count(find, haystack) { 
        return haystack.match(new RegExp(find,"gmi")).length;
    }
window.alert(replace ("hello","bye","hello world? Hello person! and hello universe!"));
window.alert("Number of matches: "+count("hello","hello world? Hello person! and hello  universe!"));
```

Comment: all of them. it matches all strings over all lines case insentive. If you run the snippet you see that it has replaced all 3 hello's. To have it case sensitive, remove the i in the Regexp object.

Comment: From the OP: "After that I want it to display an alert with a replaced words count."

Comment: Ah, missed that. added a counting function.